# how to make a file in src at webpack file

Tags: javascript, webpack

when i put "webpack" ZIP in a new folder and extract it in new folder i go to the "src" folder and then go to the terminal of "VSCODE" and write "npm install" after that "npm run build" so i can see every things in "src" folder that copied in "dist" folder , but my question is that : when i create a new folder in "src" and write "npm run build" in vscode , that new folder wont build in "dist" . in "dist" folder there is just "src" files . how can i put new folder that i have made in "src" , at "dist" folder . thanks . i made a new file in "src" and i cant see this file in "dist"

Comment: `src` and `dist` are folders and not "*files*", what is the purpose of creating multiple folders in the `dist` folder??

Answer (score 0):

By default, webpack will use `index.js` file in `src/index.js`. This may vary depending on the webpack version.

Generally, its preferred to specify the entry files. Based on your question, I'm assuming you are trying to add additional files to webpack entry that would be parsed and build by webpack.

This is handled by defining additional entry in webpack.config.js
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.js',
    vendors: './src/vendors.js',
  },
  ...
};
```

In the example above, webpack will generate two files in `dist/`.

1. `dist/main.js`
2. `dist/vendors.js`

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the question I am getting from this:**

How can I configure my webpack config so that a new file created in a given `src` folder will be processed and moved to a given `dist` folder when running `npm run build`?

**Solution:**

For a new source file to be recognized by webpack, you will either need to create a new entry in your webpack.config.js or you will need to import some exported function from your new file into an existing entry.

**Here is an example scenario:**

I have a directory `app` containing: `app/src/`, `app/dist/`, `app/webpack.config.js`, `app/src/index.js`

And when I run `npm run build`, a file called `index.bundle.js` is generated in me `app/dist` folder

I now want a new script `contact.bundle.js` generated in my `app/dist` folder when I run `npm run build`

My existing `webpack.cofig.js` file looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: "./src/index.js",
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
}
```

But I want to modify it so now my `src/contact.js` is recognized by webpack and processed as `dist/contact.bundle.js`

So I update my `webpack.config.js` file as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: "./src/index.js",
        contact: "./src/contact.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
}
```

Please comment if the answer needs to be clarified any further.